# Get static member of class passed as parameter PHP

Tags: php

```
class tables
{
    public static $database="testDB";
}

class tableHandler
{
    var $table;
    function __construct($table1)
    {
        $this->table=$table1;
        var_dump($table1::$database,$this->table::$database);
    }
}

$table=new tables();
$handler=new tableHandler($table);
```

This produces the following:

```
string(7) "testDB" 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '::'
```

How can I access `$database` of `$this->table` in `tableHandler`?

Comment: What's your PHP version? If < 7.0, upgrade first.

Comment: ... or you could stop using global state in your code

Comment: I would have a method on the tables class called `getDatabase`. It would return the static variable. i.e. `return self::$database;`. An other option is to use reflection - but that is rather complex for what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$table is an instance of class $tables so  static argument can't be access from this object

You have to use `tables::database` instead because database belongs to the class and not to the object.

Answer (score -1):

You can't do this in a straightforward way. You can use reflection or eval, in my opinion eval is the much simpler solution here - because get_class *almost* gets you what you need.

Example:

```
function __construct($table1)
{
    $this->table=$table1;
    $evalstr = '$esDataBase = ' . get_class($table1) . '::$database;';
    eval ($evalstr);
    echo $esDataBase;
}
```

You'd probably want to set a field, rather than some random variable like esDataBase.